# SBS 2011: can't open web-based Sharepoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I'm quite a newbie with Sharepoint, so please bear with me if I can't even ask the question appropriately...

We installed SBS 2011 (Sharepoint 2010) a couple of years ago and it's running fine. We **never used Sharepoint** features.

Now we wanted to explore Workflow features so I went to `http://sites` and logged in as a Sharepoint administrator (successfully).

My problem is that whenever I need to go into the **web-based Sharepoint Designer**, I get an error. The designer is active on the server, it should be available at `https://sites:987`, but I always get `Connection reset` when I browse to that address.

I even tried momentarily bringing down the Server Firewall to check if it was a firewall problem, but the same thing happens...

A distinctive circumstance of this server is that it **is not connected to the Internet** (that's a company requirement, I can connect occasionally for updates, but not permanently). I've been told this shouldn't be a problem for what I'm trying to do.

Can you please advise, and help me troubleshoot? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have SharePoint designer installed on the server? If you do not, install it first. 
Once you have the SP designer, Open it and 'Open Site' and give the URL to your site, this should do it or you should get more relevant error if there is one.

Also , you do nor need Internet to access a site from SP designer, if the SP designer is on the same server as your SharePoint Site.

If you want to access your site from a SP designer on a different machine other than your server, then you will need intranet (your internal network) at least.

Comment: Please see my comments on the other answer, it was almost simultaneous (and similar) to yours. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do so, this step will **Edit the current page**. Open SharePoint Designer from any machine, and click Open Site and connect to your site collection as http://servername/sites/SiteCollection , and from there you can navigate to the workflows section and start your workflow.

Comment: Ok, I'm starting to understand better... but I can't open SP Designer in the first place. I checked my server and the Designer is enabled, and supposedly running at `https://sites:987/`, but if I browse to that location I get a `Connection Reset`.

Comment: FYI, I can browse Webmail site on `https://sites/owa`, and Sharepoint on `https://sites/`.